# Code reusability in Styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I have a style element which has minor edits and mostly repeated. How do i make it more generic - so setter properties are set within based on value versus repeating the code twice

```
<ResourceDictionary>
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyleEnvironment" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,4,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyleLocation" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,4,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

As you see from the code all setter properties are same except Margin and FontSize. Also attached is the screenshot of it on rendering.

[image]

Please note - want to keep this self contained within a Style and not have declare at local level in XAML when this being consumed.

Possible values of Env can be Dev,QA,Prod and possible values of location can be TK, LN

Consuming in XAML snippet as follows:

```
<Grid DataContext="{....}">
   <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Environment}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyleEnvironment}"/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyleLocation}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use style inheritance:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style x:Key="BaseTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,4,0,0" />
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
  </Style>

  <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyleEnvironment" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />

  <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyleLocation" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Additionally you can create attached properties and bind to those from within your control templates. This gives you the flexibility of not having to create hundreds of styles just because something minute needs to be different.

A good example of that is a button that has an image. When the mouse is over the image, the image needs to change. Typically you'd have to create a new control template/style for each button that implements that behavior. However, if you create two attached properties - NormalStateImageSource and MosueOverImageSource, you can bind to those in your control template. This allows you to have a single full blown style for the button, and later to declare individual styles for other buttons that only change the values of these attached properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are few techniques in WPF world.

First, if styles are same type, it's possible to use `BasedOn` attribute:

```
<Style x:Key="GenericTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,4,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyleEnvironment" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource GenericTextBlockStyle}"
        TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">

</Style>
```

However the `BasedOn` attribute can get really messy sometimes. It's also possible to do it this way, which will work for elements that are not the same type:

```
<Thickness x:Key="LeftBorderMargin" Top="10" />

<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyleEnvironment" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource LeftBorderMargin}" />
</Style>
```

It's common practice to refactor all the colors / margins out from the `Style` element, for reusability.

Comment: Should i be using MultiDataTriggers here as a possible solution ?